# SVG file import

Tags: android

Whenever I am adding a .svg file to android studio as a vector asset, it is coming as a black. The color is transforming into black from any color.
I am receiving these following errors

In Attendance Report.svg:

> ERROR@ line 34 switch is not supported
>
> ERROR@ line 35 foreignObject is not supported
>
> ERROR@ line 40 linearGradient is not supported
>
> ERROR@ line 41 stop is not supported
>
> ERROR@ line 42 stop is not supported
>
> ERROR@ line 43 stop is not supported
>
> ERROR@ line 44 stop is not supported
>
> ERROR@ line 45 stop is not supported
>
> ERROR@ line 46 stop is not supported
>
> ERROR@ line 47 stop is not supported

where am i getting wrong? need suggesion.

Comment: You need to convert SVG file to vector then you able to use it. http://prntscr.com/jxlh1u

Comment: @Akash see my answer

Answer (score 0):

Gradient color feature is not supported yet in Android Studio (current ver is 2.2) so it doesn't help you with autocomplete but marks gradient tag as an error instead. Nevertheless, the feature does actually work, I've tested it successfully on Nexus 5X / API 24. Of course, you have to use an API 24+ device because otherwise this feature is not supported by OS.

Comment: I am using android studio(version 2.3.3).I am not receiving any problem when i am downloading any svg file from sites but when iam creating svg file, I am getting this problem.

Comment: because you are using linearGradient